# JS communication to iOS client

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, communication

I have a js page which talks to an existing android client.

JS code:

```
export function sendData(data: Array<String>, callback: String) {
    if (window.androidClient) {
       window.androidClient.sendData(data, callback);
    } else if (window[callback) {
      //processing callbackData
    }
}
```

I want to use the existing code for talking to iOS as well.

If we are using WKWebKit, I can see articles suggesting to use

```
webkit.messageHandlers.<myHandler>.postMessage()
```

Is there any way to implement iOS without any changes is js code.
Any pointers/code is appreciated.

Thanks!